# Elapsed time in pandas time series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas time-series dataframe and I want to know the total elapsed time of the dataframe or points within the dataframe. How do I do this?

The following is some example data from my dataframe:

```
elapsed_time           Layer
1970-01-01 00:20:30    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:31    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:32    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:33    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:34    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:35    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:36    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:37    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:38    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:39    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:40    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:41    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:42    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:43    20.0
1970-01-01 00:20:44    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:45    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:46    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:47    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:48    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:49    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:50    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:51    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:52    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:53    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:54    21.0
1970-01-01 00:20:55    22.0
1970-01-01 00:20:56    22.0
1970-01-01 00:20:57    22.0
1970-01-01 00:20:58    22.0
1970-01-01 00:20:59    22.0
1970-01-01 00:21:00    22.0
1970-01-01 00:21:01    22.0
1970-01-01 00:21:02    22.0
1970-01-01 00:21:03    22.0
1970-01-01 00:21:04    22.0
```

For example I want to know how long layer 21 took. Is there any simple method or function to get the elapsed time of the index? I had no problem doing this when the `elapsed_time` was part of the dataframe but I can't get it to work when it's the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to reset the index in order to have access to the timestamp as a column for the group by:

```
res = df.reset_index().groupby('Layer')['elapsed_time'].agg(['min', 'max'])  
res['max'] - res['min']
```

You can also use `first` and `last` if you know your data is sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that doesn't help while my time data is the index. I don't understand how to get the elapsed time out of the index.